# MYSQL setting Foreign Key ERROR 1452 (23000)

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have users and rota table in my mysql database and trying to add set a Foreign key called user_id in my rota table. But I get this error after executing this line of code in the terminal:

ALTER TABLE rota ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id);

and the error is:

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sharp2_development`.`#sql-b19_ada`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-b19_ada_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

I have a user_id column in rota with the type int, NO NULL, default no and no extra 
my user table's id is same apart from it being a Primary key and auto_increment.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? You can't add the constraint because one of your `user_id` values isn't a `users.id`.

Comment: Give your table definitions and values. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).